# Update img src on button press

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook-graph-api

I've written a simple function to grab an authenticated user's profile picture and set an `<img>` to that. While the `src` attribute is updating properly, the image doesn't actually change.

```
function getDefault(){
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
        $('#default').val("http://graph.facebook.com/" + response.id + "/picture");
    });
    alert($('#default').val());
    }
```

...

```
<img id="default" src="getDefault()"/>
<button onclick="getDefault()">Click to see your profile picture!</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute isn't "value". It's "src". So... it should be like this:

```
$('#getDefault').click(function(){
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
        $('#default').attr('src', 'http://graph.facebook.com/' + response.id + '/picture');
        alert($('#default').attr('src'));
    });

});

<img id="default" src="getDefault()"/>
<button id="getDefault">Click to see your profile picture!</button>
```

Update?: Also, the Alert should be inside because maybe you won't get any value outside...

Answer (score 1):

Why would you set the `src` to a function call that doesn't return a value?  That's going to give you an undefined .src value. `src` needs to be  a URL.  You can achieve that either by returning a URL from your function or setting the `.src` property directly to a URL.  Also, an image doesn't have a `.value` property.

Change your HTML to this:

```
<img id="default"/>
<button id="getDefault">Click to see your profile picture!</button>
```

And your JS to this:

```
$('#getDefault').click(function(){
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
        $("#default").attr('src', 'http://graph.facebook.com/' + response.id + '/picture');
    });
});
```

Comment: do you mean that the id of the button should be `getDefault`, not a function call on click?

Comment: @Chris - sorry I don't understand your question.

Comment: your button's `onclick="getDefault"` but wouldn't the .click function override that?

Comment: Yes, there was a typo in my answer which I've corrected.  I meant for the button to have an id value.